# Vue2 Mutations Why just the first element is committed?

Tags: vuejs2, store

I have a store with the following mutation:

```
state{
 itemsBought: [],
},
mutations: {
    buyItemsInTheShop: (state, payload) =>
      {console.log(payload)
        state.itemsBought.push(payload)
  }},
```

And a code in AlcoholShop.vue file:

```
computed: {
    itemsBought() {
      console.log("@itemsbought")
      console.log(this.$store.state.itemsBought)
      return this.$store.state.itemsBought;
    }},
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['buyItemsInTheShop']),
   buyItems() {
      console.log("@itemsToBeBought")
      console.log(...this.itemsToBeBought)
      this.buyItemsInTheShop(...this.itemsToBeBought);
      this.tooglePages();
    },
```

when I try to add more than one item to the cart I cannot do it only the first one is added - can anyone tell me why?

e.g. when I select two items and I console.log(...this.itemsToBeBought) I get an array of two objects but when I console.log(this.$store.state.itemsBought) only the first item is added.

How to fix it so that two items were added? I would be grateful for assistance.

Comment: I have already solved it using forEach:
this.itemsToBeBought.forEach((item) => this.buyItemsInTheShop(item));

Answer (score 0):

Pass array to mutation:

```
this.buyItemsInTheShop(this.itemsToBeBought);
```

Then concat arrays:

```
state.itemsBought = state.itemsBought.concat(payload)
```